# Nxt / Ardor not downloading blockchain, it just stuck and hangs on startup at "known peers"

Tags: blockchain, nxt, ardor

I have a fresh install of nxt / ardor and it just hangs on "Known Peers:". I waited a few hours and nothing happens. How can one debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your firewall allows outgoing connections on port 7874 or 6874 on testnet.

You can also try to invoke the getPeers API from the http://localhost:7876/test page with "active" set to "true". You should see a list of IPs your connected to, if you don't see anything, double check your 7874 port.